# Changing the size of a figure in CSS doesn't affect the image size inside of it

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the size of a figure in CSS, the image inside of it remains the original size

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center">
        <p>        
            Piece of text inside a 500px width div centered on the page
        </p>

        <figure>
            <img src="https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg">
        </figure>
    </div><!--wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

figure {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: auto;
}

p {
    clear: both;
}
```

When I modify the width attribute in the css, it doesn't affect the size of the image shown on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
figure > img {
    width: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign `width` and `height` to your `img`. Now whenever you change you `figure` `height` and `width` this to changes according to it.

```
figure > img{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a max width on the image.

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```